# Clear previous cached options in jQuery chosen for new AJAX submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

auto-populating the values in jquery chosen on key press event for the values typed in the chosen field. In first request, it is fine. but for the furthur keypress event, the values are getting appended to the previous appended options. below is my callback code.

```
success: function(data) {
each(data, function(index) {
$(".chzn-select").append(
$('<option></option>')
.val(data[index])
.html(data[index]));
});
$(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
}
```

Is it possible to clear the chosen optioned values before the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the jquery to do ajax requests without caching.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

With this, jQuery will add a parameter named `_` on your url with a random number and it will make a diferent request and url everything to the server avoiding browser caching. You also can configure cache in your `$.ajax` command, for sample:

```
$.ajax({
   // configs...
   cache: false,
   // configs...
});
```

Comment: Ajax call is not cached. the values appeneded in the chosen are getting added up with the previous appeneded values. need to clear the previous appended values and add the new values which got from the keypress event(ajax call)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `.append` and never clear the data manually. The succeeding ajax request is not in any way “connected” to the select/chosen box. The simplest way would be to clear all options before using `$(".chzn-select").html("");`. However, that may cause an additional DOM update when resetting and for each new item. The code below collects all options beforehand and inserts them in one go instead:

```
// safely store original options in an array. You only need to call
// this once. It's probably best to run this before initiating chosen()
// to avoid possible conflicts.
var originalOptions = [];
$(".chzn-select").children("option").each(function(ind, elm) { 
    originalOptions.push(elm);
});
// init chosen after
$(".chzn-select").chosen();


// (the other code here)

success: function(data) {
  var newOptions = [];
  $.each(data, function(index) {
    newOptions.push($('<option/>').val(data[index]).html(data[index]).get(0));
  });

  // this line will clear *all* entries in the select. Therefore
  // we combine originalOptions and newOptions, so that the original
  // options are kept. If you want the ajax options to be listed first,
  // switch the variables.
  $(".chzn-select").html(originalOptions.concat(newOptions));
  $(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: It clears not only the options i populated in the previous AJAX call, it clears the values in the chosen select box also...

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to only have AJAX completion. I updated my post so that the original options in the select are kept. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add below function to the  Chosen.jquery.js

```
Chosen.prototype.activate_field = function() {
  this.container.addClass("chzn-container-active");
  this.active_field = true;
  this.search_field.val(this.search_field.val());
  this.clear_prev_list();
  return this.search_field.focus();
};


 Chosen.prototype.clear_prev_list = function() {
    return this.container.find("li.active-result").remove(); 
  };
```

This is resolve ur problem